# How to get actual size of ai_addr->sa_data returned by getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, network-programming, getaddrinfo

getaddrinfo() fills `struct addrinfo` where actual packed address stored in `struct sockaddr *ai_addr` field. `struct sockaddr` has field `char *sa_data` with actual binary address representation. I want to copy this sa_data to another variable using `memcpy()`, for this I need to know actual length of this field.

I thinked ai_addrlen is what I need. But in fact it returns 16 for IPv4 and 28 for IPv6. Too much I think. So, what is the most correct way to get sa_data length? May be `length = sa_family == AF_INET ? 4 : 16` or `length = ai_addrlen - 12`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getaddrinfo()` function returns a linked list consisting of `struct addrinfo` records. Each of those records includes a pointer to `struct sockaddr` which is a polymorphic type, behind which there is actually a `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6`. The `ai_addrlen` member tells you how large is that structure, i.e. returns either `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in6)`.

Those structures contain the binary IP address, the port number (for the transport protocol like TCP or UDP), the family (repeated in `struct addrinfo` as well) and other data (flowinfo and scope_id for IPv6, when looking at linux docs).

The actual binary address is inside the `struct sockaddr_in` and `strict sockaddr_in6` as `struct in_addr sin_addr` and `struct in6_addr sin6_addr`. You can use those fields or types to determine the size.

```
length = sa_family == AF_INET ? sizeof (struct in_addr) : sizeof (struct in6_addr)
```

As those are known numbers, you can of course use what you have already in your question.

```
length = sa_family == AF_INET ? 4 : 16
```

But you also tried to do arithmetics on `ai_addrlen` and that is not a good idea, as the types can vary by operating system and there's no logic in that anyway. I can add more details if you had a specific use case or specific code.